# Create new line inside Linear Layout

Tags: android, gridview, android-linearlayout, android-gridview

[References Image](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipN8CMwXwKf_8AJtaclkZTq-iDy8TtLzjSFc-pq5RFwyB05KiQUUozHhtez7Q1gxfA?key=ZlhTS1hYWEc0amZUeUpoTU1PS1pXVm1OQjhDRkd3)

**What I want:** dynamically add the image inside the box and if a line is complete then add it to new line.

**WHere I am currently:** I am able to add the image inside the linear layout, if no of image is greater than the block width then remaining image will not shown.

**What is the issue:** Since I am adding to the linear layout and I am not telling the layout where I should be added. SO it add at the end of the row.

**Solution Tried:** :

I have added the gridview with the 3 column inside the linear layout.But in this approach, I am able to figure about how to calculate the position where I add image. Since in grid view we can't find the position of last item filled. 
One more problem with this approach I need to track last item position.

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout

            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Morning"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Afternoon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_curve"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:id="@+id/ll1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0">

               <!-- <GridView
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_curve"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:id="@+id/gv1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    </GridView>-->
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_curve"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/ll2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0">

                <!--<GridView
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_curve"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:id="@+id/gv2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                </GridView>
-->

            </LinearLayout>


         </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Evening"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Night"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_curve"
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0">

<!--
        <GridView
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_curve"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:id="@+id/gv3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </GridView>-->

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_curve"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/ll4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0">


           <!-- <GridView
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_curve"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:id="@+id/gv4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </GridView>
-->
                </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_reminders"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml code.

Comment: code added @SnehaSarkar

Answer (score 1):

You may use `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` attribute to your gridview. It will automatically fit according to the number of images.

```
 <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gvFrameBook"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"/>
```

Then you can add your linearlayout programmatically in getview() method of adapter class. To add linearlayout to your gridview you may consider following example

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.put_linearlayout_here, parent, false);
        ivImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImg);}
```

Inside your "put_linearlayout_here.xml" you add linearlayout (with your cherished background ) and inside it add an imageview with id "ivImg". Hope this helps.

Comment: how will I add the linearlayout in getview()?

Comment: can you look into my code, https://docs.google.com/a/betterconnectplus.com/document/d/1iz3il5T9a8qAn3dJMeX5RqDvkBXVoHtCI_BQcYJBrxI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i have edited my answer. Let me know if it suffices.

Comment: ivImg will declare in put_linearlayout_here.xml file?

Comment: yes, you just shift your linearlayout and imageview to another xml file(put_linearlayout_here.xml). Then you inflate this xml file into the gridview and he will take care of everything from there :) Btw, have you set any adapter to your gridview in your activity class ?