# fill every line of LinearLayout with correct count of items

Tags: android

this is my xml layout :

---

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1000"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2000"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3000"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4000"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5000"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6000"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7000"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8000"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

---

when i set orientation of LinearLayout to horizontal

result is like this :

[image]

when i set orientation of LinearLayout to vertical

result is like this :

[image]

i need a result like this :

[image]

**HOW I CAN DO THAT?**

> without use a LinearLayout for each line; I need do that, like when we use *display='inline-block'* for inner items of a div tag in HTML

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use LinearLayout for this.
But you can check this out [Create new line inside Linear Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330807/create-new-line-inside-linear-layout)